# Find out wether the child has the 2 classes that I need, without foreach?

Tags: jquery, html

can I find 2 classes in same html-tag/html-container without using a foreach ?

I was thinking of something like this, to find out whether the same child  has 2 classes:

```
$(".btnUploadWrapper").children().hasClass("postFileSuccess").hasClass("hidden")
```

or

```
$(".btnUploadWrapper").children().hasClass("postFileSuccess hidden")
```

Is it possible ?

Comment: Yes, that's good, but how about the other way round, if one child should only contain a single class ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find` on the parent to get **all** the elements with the two classes inside them. You can directly use the elementy any further:

```
var elements = $(".btnUploadWrapper").find(".postFileSuccess.hidden");
```

If you only want to get the **direct** children, you can do the same with `children` too:

```
var elements = $(".btnUploadWrapper").children(".postFileSuccess.hidden");
```

Comment: Don't forget that `find()` goes all the way down the DOM tree from the first element, whereas the OPs original usage of `children()` only gets child elements

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a loop directly, you could try and select the elements and check the `length` of the resulting jQuery object:

```
var $matched = $(".btnUploadWrapper > .postFileSuccess.hidden");
if ($matched.length) {
    // there are some matching elements...
}
```